# Retrieving SharePoint site author and permissions through Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to retrieve Sharepoint subsites authors & permissions (public or private, and if private : allowed groups/members), preferably using Graph API.

For **Outlook Groups** and **Teams** sites, I can use endpoints `/groups/<groupID>`, `/groups/<groupID>/owners` and `/groups/<groupID>/members` to achieve that, but it seems that there is no equivalent for sites created through the following process:

- Load "root site" https://<yourdomain>.sharepoint.com
- Click on "Site contents" > "New" > "Subsite"

The only "interesting" Graph API endpoint I found yet, is `/sites/root/sites/<siteID>/lists`, returning some site metadata (collections of data like "master pages", "designs"...), along with a `createdBy` structure (containing a `user.id` property) for each of those collections.

However, using it would look hacky, a "direct" property/structure `author` or `owners` would be preferable. Moreover, the `/sites/.../lists` endpoint is only available in *beta* version of the API (has somebody any info on its release date ?), and still, that does not tells me which users are allowed to view the site.

Attempts with other APIs like [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124980/how-to-access-sharepoint-2013-site-owners-with-rest-api) did not provide any closer info to what I need.

Thanks for any piece of advice.

Comment: Concerning the SharePoint site author, it can be retrieved using endpoint/method:

https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/<your-subsite>/_api/web/Author

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has site collections > sites > lists > folders > items. By default each object inherits permissions from its parent, but you can break inheritance at any level. So in order to get a complete picture of the permissions a subsite has, you will need to enumerate every object inside that subsite (lists, folder, items) and check if it inherits permissions from its parent or not. As far as I know Microsoft Graph doesn't expose an API that lets you do this, but you can instead use SharePoint CSOM (client side object model) or SharePoint REST APIs.