# Retrieving SharePoint Online objects permissions via Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I need to map permissions for all SharePoint Online objects (Sites, Lists, List Items, Attachments, Files, Folders). It seems to be possible through the CSOM API, but haven't found anything similar in Microsoft Graph.

The following query successfully [retrieves a requested item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N4ff.png):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/Lists/{List ID}/items/{item ID}/
```

But the following query doesn't return the permissions as I expected:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/Lists/{List ID}/items/{item ID}/permissions
```

I received the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'permissions'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ab9f4cfe-f0e1-433b-9767-96d4b3e58c59",
            "date": "2019-03-18T18:52:21"
        }
    }
}
```

The same error was received upon the following query as well:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/root/Lists/{List ID}/permissions
```

A year ago [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431564/retrieving-sharepoint-site-author-and-permissions-through-graph-api) was asked, and the answer was that it is not possible.

Is it possible now? If yes then what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither the [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list#properties) or [`ListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem#properties) resource documentation shows `permissions` as a valid property or relationship.

If the `List` is a Document Library, then you can use the associated [`DriveItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem#relationships) to view it's [`permission`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission) collection:

```
GET /v1.0/sites/root/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveitem/permissions
```

For example, executing `/v1.0/sites/root/lists/eacf1ff2-7f98-4f71-963a-44e0cf35f608/items/4/driveitem/permissions` in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=sites/root/lists/eacf1ff2-7f98-4f71-963a-44e0cf35f608/items/4/driveitem/permissions&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com) returns:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('root')/lists('eacf1ff2-7f98-4f71-963a-44e0cf35f608')/items('4')/driveItem/permissions",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "VGVhbSBTaXRlIE93bmVycw",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "grantedTo": {
        "user": {
          "displayName": "Team Site Owners"
        }
      },
      "inheritedFrom": {}
    },
    {
      "id": "VGVhbSBTaXRlIFZpc2l0b3Jz",
      "roles": ["read"],
      "grantedTo": {
        "user": {
          "displayName": "Team Site Visitors"
        }
      },
      "inheritedFrom": {}
    },
    {
      "id": "VGVhbSBTaXRlIE1lbWJlcnM",
      "roles": ["write"],
      "grantedTo": {
        "user": {
          "displayName": "Team Site Members"
        }
      },
      "inheritedFrom": {}
    },
    //...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Indeed the   GET /v1.0/sites/root/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveitem/permissions retrieved the permissions on the specific item. But is there a way to retrieve all permissions on the site, or specific list?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The `Drive` APIs support permissions but not the `Site` or `List` APIs.

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/fa9c83ba-e4cb-43e7-b00d-cceb7a3a1ad4/lists/7b3815ab-5bd9-49f4-b99b-69bb8b7a62cf/items/1/driveitem/permissions

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Cannot request driveItem for an item that is not in a document library",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-03-02T07:46:28",
            "request-id": "ef9ca55a-74c0-4498-a040-2349ea03b2fe",
            "client-request-id": "29419c1b-b33e-ec2e-4ad4-b480779a86b2"
        }
    }
}
```